# A short Riley Riddle that only goes one way

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> My prefix is not a dub
>
> My infix is a common base
>
> My suffix is a quingenti sub
>
> My whole is a common replace

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My prefix is not a dub

> L for lose - dub is a slang abbreviation for the letter W (double-u) usually for a win.

My infix is a common base

> $e$ is the base of the natural logarithm.

My suffix is a quingenti sub

> D - 500 in Roman numerals.

My whole is a common replace

> LED - light-emitting diode, replacing other light bulbs. Diodes only let electricity flow in one direction.

Comment: That was pretty quick, congrats!

Answer (score 3):

Could you be

> PROTEND?

*My prefix is not a dub*

> PRO. One meaning of "dub" is "an inexperienced or unskilful person", and a pro would be the opposite.

*My infix is a common base*

> TEN, a common base for human number systems.

*My suffix is a quingenti sub*

> D, the Roman numeral for 500.

*My whole is a common replace*

> PROTEND seems like a typo for the commoner word PORTEND.

Title:

> PROTEND means [to extend or stretch forth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/protend) (in one direction).

Comment: Nice answer! Unfortunately not the one I was looking for, although you got one of the fixes right ;)